# Extract all subfolders of a path in Elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I want to extract all direct subfolders in a path field in elasticsearch.

For example I want all subfolders of this path: /path/to/file

These URLs should match

```
/path/to/file/subfolderA
/path/to/file/subfolder-b
/path/to/file/subfolder_c
```

These URLs should not match

```
/path/to/file/subfolderA/folderc
/path/to/file/subfolder-b/folderd/folderE
```

I tried with this regex query but it's not working. The part with the / is not working. But when I replace de / with a letter the query works. I tried to escape the / with a \ but it's not working either.

```
POST index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
      "regexp":{
          "path_parent": "(/path/to/file/.*)&~(.*/.*)"
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use negated character classes:

```
"path_parent": "/path/to/file/[^/]*"
                              ^^^^^
```

Since ElasticSearch patterns are anchored by default this pattern will match all paths starting with `/path/to/file/` and then having 0+ chars other than `/` followed with end of string.